# What's the "Unix way" for a CLI app to report no arguments specified?

Tags: command-line, arguments

I'm developing an application which I'd like to follow the "Unix way."

What should I program it to do in case it is called with no arguments (which makes no practical sense):

- display an error message
- display help, or
- exit silently returning `0` considering the task specified (which is nothing to do) was successfully accomplished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends what kinds of arguments your application expects. If it processes files, it's traditional to read from standard input and write to standard output if no arguments are specified (example: `cat`, `tee`, …). If the application has an interactive mode, start it if no arguments are specified (example: `sh`, `ed`). If the application expects an object to work on, show an error message and exit with a non-zero status (example: `cp`, `rm`). If the application expects a command, show a usage message and exit with a non-zero status (example: `sed`, `tar`).

Answer (score 6):

Most common variants:

- display short version of application help with clause "To view full help type app-name --help";
- display credits and license;
- "error: no operation specified (use -h for help)".

Comment: If the program can read from standard input (something most Unix CLI commands can do), it's also acceptable to simply wait for input. For instance, `cat` will do this.